# Trying to add another parameter on my URI

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, uri

I encountered this error and I don't know what is the reason why I have this error Complex object types cannot be converted to simple values. This is the code that I have

```
<cfif not parameterexists(redirected) 
    and ( qf eq 'http://www.johnjhoward.com' 
          or qf eq 'www.johnjhoward.com' 
          or qf eq 'johnjhoward.com' 
      )
 >

    <cfoutput>
     <cfquery name="stno" datasource="#idxName#"
           maxrows=1 dbtype="ODBC">
       select field50 
       from _r 
       where field1 = #mls# 
      </cfquery>    

      <script type="text/javascript">
           window.top.location = "http://www.johnjhoward.com/listings/#mls#/#stno#";
      </script>
    </cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Rewriting a feature when it's standard in all browsers looks like a waste of time if you ask me...

Comment: I don't get it. Browser back button will not load the top of the previous page. It focuses to the last scroll position or focused element. How does rewriting it could be waste of time?

Comment: Hi janaka. I'am not talking about the back button of the browser itself, What Im trying to say is that, I create a back button. Then the back button the I created is working but I want that button to reload on top of the previous page.

Comment: A search on that error message should have turned up a ton of results, explaining it means exactly what it says. You are trying to use a "complex" object (ie your query #stno#) as if it were a "simple" value like a string.  Nothing to do with the error, but there are several other issues with the code a) ParameterExists and dbtype="ODBC" have been deprecated for a long time b) The query is vulnerable to sql injection. Use `cfqueryparam` c) Queries do not need to be enclosed in `cfoutput` and d) There is noticeable lack of variable scoping.